# Python two dictionaries in dictionary, increase value in specific key

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, key

I want to increase value in dictionary of a dictionary, there is a major dictionary 'a' which has two separate dictionaries: 'be' and 'ce'. I want to increase value of specific key, determined by variables like 'dist' and 'bec' but I cannot reach the key of one of the minor dictionaries:

```
import collections
from collections import defaultdict

a={}
be = {}
ce = {}

for z in range(1,11):
    be["b_{0}".format(z)] = 0
    be = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(be.items()))

for c in range(1,11):
    for b in range(1,11):
        ce["c_{0}_{1}".format(c,b)]= 0
ce = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(ce.items()))

for x in range(1,10):
    a["a_{0}".format(x)] = be,ce
    a = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(a.items()))

dist = 3
bec = 10
a["a_"+str(dist)]["b_"+str(bec)] += 1
```

I tried to print "a["a_"+str(dist)]["b_"+str(bec)]" but it didnt work, it only works when I print only "a["a_"+str(dist)]"

Comment: When you print out `a["a_" + str(dist)]` you can see that it is a tuple. That is what the comma in `be, ce` produces. Hence the error message `tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str`. What do you want the value to be?

Comment: I want integer values for the key "b_10" of "a_3" so I could increase its value from 0 to more, each time I need it

Comment: Where does `ce` come into that? And what should be the difference between `a[a_1]` and `a[a_2]`?

Comment: 'ce' is a dictionary which is inside 'a' dictionary (so as 'be' dictionary). I want to add value for example to key 'b_9' of 'a_2' whenever dist = 2 and bec = 10. Analogous case with 'ce': with another two variables called 'for_ce1' = 5, and 'for_ce2' = 3 and with 'dist' = 1, I want to store some value where key is 'c_5_3' (means 'c_'+for_ce1+"_"+for_ce2) in 'ce' dictionary which is the key of 'a' dictionary called 'a_1' (means 'a_'+dist)

Comment: Basically I have one dictionary with two subdictionaries and I want to increase their values from 0 to higher if the name of the 'a' key and the name of either 'be' key or 'ce' key equals to specific variables: dist, bec or dist,for_ce1, for_ce2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the simplest possible approach:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = Counter()
>>> a[(3, 'b', 10)] += 1
>>> a[(3, 'b', 10)] += 1
>>> a[(3, 'b', 10)]
2
>>> a[(3, 'b', 8)]
0
```

Is there any way in which this doesn't work?

Comment: Not exactly what I meant, I am operating on dictionaries: {a_1: {(b_1), (b_2), (c_1_1), (c_1_2)}, a_2: {(b_1), (b_2), (c_1_1), (c_1_2)}} all filled with 0 at the beginning, so when I get 'bec' = 2 and 'dist' = 2 it will only increase a_2{b_2}, the rest should be all 0

Comment: So far, when I try to increase one specific value by:
a["a_"+str(dist)]["b_"+str(bec)]) += 1
it increases all 'a_' so I get a_1{b_2} : 1 and a_2{b_2} : 1 and the first one should not have changed

Comment: @Asia a Counter is a dictionary, and all keys start at 0.

Comment: I have changed it to Counter() and it still adds value to all 'a_' keys

Comment: @Asia I'm not talking about sticking a Counter into your existing code. I'm talking about scrapping it all and just using one Counter with tuple keys. Nothing nested.

Comment: I think the problem lies in line:
a["a_"+str(dist)]["b_"+str(bec)] += 1
it should take only one 'a_' and change it's value but it takes all 'a_'. I just want to change value for example for a_1{b_2}, where the digits in names are defined by different variables

Comment: @Asia The problem is that you're creating one dict/Counter and putting that under all keys, so one object is shared. You need to make a copy or create it anew each time. Now, having said that, your approach is far too complicated in all sorts of ways. Can you explain how a single flat Counter with tuple keys doesn't meet your requirements?